# When you plead the 5th and a Judge asks you questions about it, is that conversation considered privileged?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law, us-constitution, fifth-amendment, attorney-client-privilege

If you invoke the right to not self-incriminate when testifying and the judge asks you questions in regards to whether you fear of incriminating yourself is reasonable.

Is that conversation considered privilege? Does the same rights to confidentially that apply to talks with counsel apply to it?

I wonder what the case law says. I don't know if there has ever been an attempt by government to compel a judge to give an account of a case that was before him/her. If that is even possible. I'm just wondering what assurances the witness would have that, that conversation would not be used against him/her.

SOURCE: [David SIegel's answer found here.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/74942/can-you-plead-the-5th-in-a-civil-case)

> When the privilege is asserted in a court case, the Judge may question
> the person asserting it in private, off the record, to determine
> whether the fear of incrimination is reasonable.

Comment: What makes you think the judge would ask such questions?

Comment: @phoog I have added a source as per your request.

Comment: Presumably one could plead the 5th in such conversations.  I do not think there is an exception in the constitution.

Comment: @phoog: [Hoffman v. US, 341 US 479 (1951)](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/341/479/).  Page 486 discusses circumstances where the privilege can be denied if the court determines that there is no reasonable risk of self-incrimination.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks for the link.  I read that opinion with interest, but it does not discuss questioning of a witness by a judge, nor does it indicate that any judge ever questioned the witness in this case.  Rather, the decision notes that the district court relied solely on the interrogation by the prosecutor.  The opinion says that the district court "should have" done some things differently, but it does not suggest that it should have interviewed the witness, only that it should have considered certain facts in the public record and others that are common knowledge.

Comment: [Related Q&A on how challenges to pleading the fifth are handled](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24816/how-is-the-limit-of-the-fifth-amendment-enforced).  However, there is a single answer there and it seems not to fully answer the question, as persistent "what I heard"'s and even court opinions imply there is more to a challenge than the simple question of whether adequate immunity has been provided.  I have a suspicion that there's a bit of misinformation floating behind the "judge questioning the person who invoked the 5th" claim, but it seems hard to pin down in an answer.

Comment: @User65535 There is a huge exception to the 5th Amendment written right in: "nor shall be compelled in _any criminal case_ to be a witness against himself". Thus, the 5th Amendment does not fully apply in civil and administrative cases, and testimony before Congress. The issue is when testimony as a defendant in such cases, or as a witness in another criminal case could be used to incriminate yourself, and in that case a grant of criminal immunity can be used to compel testimony. See [Bill Cosby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Cosby_sexual_assault_cases#Overturned_conviction).

Comment: @user71659 SCOTUS precedent is that the 5th can be invoked in pretty much any and every government context, be they grand juries, criminal trials, civil trials, departmental hearings, state or federal versions of the same, etc.  The main difference is that the non-criminal contexts may be able to use that invocation against you by drawing adverse references, whereas no one (juries included, though it's hard to enforce this in practice) is supposed to use it against you in any form in criminal contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a frame challenge is necessary, as the underlying assumption of the question, and in particular the material quoted from another answer, is, I understand, incorrect.

This assertion, in short, is that if an invocation of the 5th is challenged, or perhaps just "hard to understand (the validity of)", then the judge may privately question the one asserting the right for more specific details.  And from there they may then make the determination of the whether the invocation is valid.  I've heard this logic many times myself, and have had it enter my head as fact at some point or another.  It seems one of those persistent folk tales about the legal world.

My best guess is this stems from how the limits of the 5th amendment protection on self incrimination are typically phrased within major decisions, or popular summations thereof (including but not necessarily limited to, or specifically implicating, wikipedia pages).  The phrasing I am most familiar with is "an invocation of the 5th is valid if the person has a reasonable fear that the answer may be used against them in a prosecution"; perhaps modified, more accurately reflecting the jurisprudence, to add "or as a link which could lead them to evidence that could be used in a prosecution against them".

The mistake then arises in applying an everyday understanding of this phrasing: how else are you to decide if a person is being reasonable unless you question them?  Maybe they've got a good reason, maybe they have a psychotic delusion, maybe they're just trying to mess with the court for their own amusement, etc. etc.  Surely you have to investigate to find out.

But within American courts, the term "reasonable" in such a standard almost never invokes the everyday understanding like this.  Instead, it refers to some abstract and generic entity.  A "reasonable jury" is not a judgment made about the particulars of a given jury, but rather an artificial construct created within the mind(s) of the judge(s) composed of purely hypothetical and generically "reasonable" everyday people.  And the legal standard to uphold that the "reasonable" standard has been met is not whether the particular person/jury/whatever at hand was acting reasonably in the usually understood fashion.  But rather if such an imagined being/group/whatever could possibly act in such fashions.

As such, if a Judge is considering overruling an invocation of the 5th, they must invoke such an abstracted entity, within the context at hand, and see if they can construe one who reasonably invokes the protection.  The judge may be able to use certain facts about the particular entity at hand, depending. If you are invoking the 5th and the record already shows you have an extensive criminal record, the court may consider that this reasonable abstraction also has an extensive criminal record; at which point it may become clear that such a person may wish to invoke the 5th so as not to incriminate themselves in other crimes.  Even moreso if the context is a far-ranging federal grand jury investigation into organized crime, and the questions you invoked the 5th on regard your connections to events of established interest to this investigation.  And this is done without actually further questioning the person, beyond what is already in the record. All the court has to do is imagine some reasonable person with a reasonable fear within the context at hand; if it can, the invocation of the 5th is generally to be sustained.  No actual determination of the particular person's "reasonableness" is required, or really even permitted.

All of the latter hypothetical was essentially the fact of the matter in the case [Hoffman v. United States](https://supreme.justia.com/cases/federal/us/341/479/). It is a very interesting and informative read, and I think fairly accessibly written (as long as one isn't too easily thrown off the rails by the citation formatting).  It covers a great deal of how any potential challenges to the 5th are to be handled.  And the short is as I have indicated above: an abstract "reasonable" person is constructed, with such construction informed by the circumstances and knowledge at hand, and judgement of reasonableness made from there.  It specifically points out that courts should be mindful of the fact that some people earn a living by violating and evading the law, and they are protected by the 5th as thoroughly and strongly as anyone else is, so the courts should consider the question of whether it would be reasonable for such a person to have invoked the 5th when deciding if it should be upheld.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hesitant to say that the judge would pull a witness into chambers to make a determination of if the witness can plead the 5th.  Normally this debate is held between the lawyers for the party (A judge talking to the witness is an Ex Parte communication, as the witness is favorable to one side of the case.).  That said, if you are called as a witness and has a valid concern that you might be asked to testify to something that would incriminate you, you should get your own lawyer to argue on your behalf, as you are likely not a client of either attorney and thus they are not obligated to look out for your own legal interests and keep you from having to testify to anything 5th amendment.  The only time I've seen the judge question witnesses taking the 5th are in cases where the witness communicates ahead of testimony that they will be pleading the 5th to all questions, at which upon swearing in, the judge will confirm this in open court with a question to the effect of "It is my understanding that you will be exercising your 5th amendment right in the entirety of your testimony today, is that correct?" to which the witness confirms their intentions to do so, makes sure the records reflect this, and dismiss them.   The judge is not questioning them as to the nature of their exercising of their rights, but as to the intention to exercise it.

Comment: I was under the impression that these questions were usually asked so as to help decide if the witness is obstructing justice by pleading the 5th when there is no real chance that anything could incriminate them.

Comment: No.  Typically in those situations, the witness is called by a prosecutor under an agreement to testify in exchange for immunity.   The prosecutor would have this conversation with the judge who would instruct the witness to answer the questions as asked.  The judge doesn't ask the witness for his reasoning (generally immunity deals imply any crimes that come out in testimony.).  Additionally if you've already been convicted of a crime, you cannot plead the 5th, because double jeopardy.

Comment: @hszmv: But what about a civil case, where no prosecutor is involved?  Imagine an uncooperative witness, testifying under subpoena, who pleads the fifth to every question including "Is your name Fred Smith?"  Are you suggesting that the witness can't be ordered to answer unless a prosecutor can be gotten to show up and offer a grant of immunity?  (Two prosecutors actually - because the witness could pretend that the answer would incriminate them for both state and federal crimes.)

Comment: @NateEldredge You can't plead the fifth if you have immunity.   You can only do so if you are at risk for criminal prosecution.  While you can invoke your right to not testify against yourself in a Civil Case, because Civil Cases require a lower burden of proof to find fault against a party in the case, refusing to testify in a civil case will almost always hurt your case.  Unlike in criminal cases, a jury is allowed to use your refusal to testify against you in their deliberations.

Comment: Let's say the witness has no particular stake in the case, so doesn't care if the the refusal will hurt one party or the other.  They are not actually at any risk of criminal prosecution but are merely pretending to be, so as to avoid answering the questions.  Your argument seems to be that the court must take them at their word, and cannot inquire into whether the risk of prosecution is genuine; and that the only way to make them answer questions is to convince the relevant prosecutors to grant immunity.  Do I understand correctly?

Comment: No...  There are times that have no immunity granted.  Suppose you're asked a question about a previous crime for which you were tried (whether or not you were found guilty).  You cannot plead the fifth because you cannot be tried twice for the same crime.

Comment: @NateEldredge However, there are times you would have a valid need to plead the 5th without ever answering for a crime.  Suppose a witness is unbeknownst to the attorney, undercover investigating an unrelated matter.   He's asked if Jimmy Jones is his legal name, to which he invokes his ffth amendment right against self-incrimination.  The reason is Jimmy Jones is his cover name.  If he answers yes, he's lied under oath, which is a crime.  If he says, no, he's blowing his cover which can put him into mortal danger.   A 5A plea resolves this in a way that avoids the issue.

Comment: @hszmv: Yes, certainly, it *could* be legitimate.  But in this case it isn't.  So by your argument, this is a way to get out of answering any question that the witness happens not to wish to answer, so long as there exists some theoretical way, even if extremely farfetched, that such a question could incriminate someone.

Comment: @hszmv: More concrete hypothetical.  Fred Smith was a bystander who witnessed an auto accident, and the plaintiff thinks his testimony will make their case (e.g. he could see that the defendant ran a red light).    He has committed no crimes whatsoever.  However, the accident took place on the block where his mistress lives, at a time when his wife thought he was at the office, so he doesn't want to admit having been there, but he also doesn't want to perjure himself or be held in contempt.  So he dishonestly pleads the fifth to every question.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be that Fred's strategy will work, he'll successfully avoid answering any questions, and that the plaintiff is out of luck and simply won't be able to have his testimony about the red light.  What if every witness in every trial decided to use this strategy?

Comment: It's their right to.   Eyewitness testimony is generally considered to be the worst kind of evidence anyway.   Plaintiff should have asked around for camera footage to prove his case.

Comment: Okay, but the camera footage would have to be authenticated by the testimony of the person who collected it, right?  What if they also decide to plead the fifth for no good reason?  (Or, if you like, add to the hypothetical that the year is 1963.)  Anyway, I think that I now understand your position, but I am skeptical of it, so I will see what I can find out for myself.

Comment: @NateEldredge You can throw any hypothetical you want.  The 5th amendment right against self-incrimination is the right of anyone who is asked to give sworn testimony that would implicate them in a crime.   There's no process for determining if they honestly have that fear or are lying to avoid testimony because making a determination like that voids the whole right.

Comment: So in fact, the court is allowed to determine that no such danger exists, and to order a witness to answer, on penalty of contempt.  See Hoffman v. United States, 341 U.S. 479 (1951).  "But this protection must be confined to instances where the witness has reasonable cause to apprehend danger from a direct answer. Mason v. United States, 244 U. S. 362, 244 U. S. 365 (1917), and cases cited. The witness is not exonerated from answering merely because he declares that, in so doing he would incriminate himself -- his say-so does not of itself establish the hazard of incrimination." [...]

Comment: " It is for the court to say whether his silence is justified, Rogers v. United States, 340 U. S. 367 (1951), and to require him to answer if "it clearly appears to the court that he is mistaken." Temple v. Commonwealth, 75 Va. 892, 899 (1880). "  There is some further explanation to of how that determination can be made - though in particular, it does not require the witness to prove the claim.

Comment: hszmv "If he answers yes, he's lied under oath, which is a crime": pleading the fifth to avoid committing perjury (or any other crime) is not a valid reason to plead the fifth.  @NateEldredge it's clear that courts can find that a witness's invocation of fifth amendment privilege is unjustified, but I don't see any evidence that the process of making that determination involves a judge asking the witness questions (much less off the record) as posited in this question.