# What happens if a witness invokes the 5th and is forced to answer?

Tags: constitutional-law

[Follow up question to this one.](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/91195/when-you-plead-the-5th-and-a-judge-asks-you-questions-about-it-is-that-conversa)

What would happen if a witness invokes his right not to self-incriminate the judge deems it unreasonable and tells the witness to answer the question and by doing so it he does end up incriminating himself?

Answer (score 3):

[canada](/questions/tagged/canada)

Canada has a similar protection. [Section 13 of the *Canadian Charter of Rights and Freedoms*](https://www.justice.gc.ca/eng/csj-sjc/rfc-dlc/ccrf-ccdl/check/art13.html) says that:

> A witness who testifies in any proceedings has the right not to have any incriminating evidence so given used to incriminate that witness in any other proceedings, except in a prosecution for perjury or for the giving of contradictory evidence.

The person is protected against the use of their compelled testimony or any evidence derived therefrom in any subsequent criminal proceedings (other than for perjury).